# Braintree API in PHP - enforce currency for transaction

Tags: php, paypal, transactions, braintree

I am trying to enforce a currency for a transaction via the Braintree API but I cannot see how this is done. Stripe is very easy, as the currency (AUD, USD) is passed to the Stripe server as part of the execution.

With Braintree what I can see is that the currency is dependent on the merchant account receiving the money. My app will allow a user to invoice their customer, so the user will select the presentment currency of the invoice. I want to lock this selection to their merchant account currency.

If I understood this correctly, then pushing a transaction of MYR 250 (for example) and having a customer pay for this, if the merchant account behind the transaction is a EUR account, then the customer was presented by my app a MYR 250 value, but his CC is debited a EUR 250 value.

Is there a way to do this with Braintree? I want to do this with the standard merchant accounts and not under the Master Merchant set up.

Alternatively, is there a way to confirm the currency of an account from the Merchant Id / keys that a user supplies my app?

I have read the entire API docs, but I cannot see how this is done. Did i miss something? It has been a long week already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

It's possible to have different presentment currencies and settlement currencies. To set this up, please check out this [section](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/get-started/currencies#multi-currency-setups) and email the Braintree Accounts team directly: accounts@braintreepayments.com

To confirm the currency associated with a MerchantAccount, you can call [`MerchantAccount.find`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/merchant-account/find/ruby) using a `merchant_account_id`. With the MerchantAccount object, you can check its [`currency_iso_code`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/merchant-account/ruby#currency_iso_code) attribute.

Comment: You rock @Mimarshall, thanks. Wish the other BT boys would have answered my email with this 5 days ago...